# gRPC running along side with Asp.net Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application, asp.net-core-mvc, grpc

**Problem Background**

I currently have two projects that link to the same database. The first application is an Asp.Net Core MVC project using entity framework. It hosts a bunch of dashboards and REST APIs.

The second project is an Asp.Net Core Console application which hosts a [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) server on a separate port.

The third project is an intermediate Schema project which serves the models as a class library for the two above projects.

**Question**

Would it be possible/better to host the gRPC project in the same project as the MVC project? If so then would there be no conflicts in the thread pools of kestrel/grpc? Lastly would this remove the ability to host the application on an IIS server using IISIntergration?

**TL;DR**
Can/Should I host both a gRPC and MVC server on aspnet core using the same project and what would be the repercussions?

Comment: You would definitely want to have an HTTP endpoint in the same service, which serves gRPC for the purpose of healthchecks and metrics collection, which is currently only done via HTTP if you look at Prometheus and K8S.

Answer (score 4):

For the part of the question about thread pool conflicts:

> If so then would there be no conflicts in the thread pools of kestrel/grpc?

GRPC spawns its own thread pool to do work and complete tasks related to grpc calls. As long as the async/await is used everywhere and potentially long-running CPU work is offloaded, then there shouldn't be any problems on this end.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly ASP.NET Core now officially supports GRPC natively since version 3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio